# Force external display's rate to non-adaptive

Tags: display, monterey

Every time that I connect my Dell monitor to my laptop (Macbook Pro) it defaults to the adaptive refresh rate and I don't like it when switching between spaces with dark full-screen applications.

I would like for this external monitor to default to a constant refresh (either 100 or 60 Hz) I don't mind. Just not adaptive.

Any ideas?

Comment: To adjust settings on a DELL monitor you may need to consult Dell support. Dell monitors do have an OSD (On Screen [settings] Display) that may allow that adjustment, dell.com/support would have the instructions for your specific display.

Comment: Hi Steve, thank you for your reply. In the monitor, there is not any such option. It gives three refresh options (normal, fast, and extreme) none of which is adaptive. I believe that this has to do with the OS options defaulting to adaptive every time I reconnect.

Comment: I would call Dell support, get to a level 2 guy (I have done this at Dell in Austin) and have him/her find out for you. *Never assume* in tech support if it is not officially documented, treat it with suspicion. Also adaptive may just be exactly what is happening: *the Mac adapting to whatever the monitor says it is."